# Div overlay error inside table cell

Tags: html, iframe, overlay

I have this code:

```
<td width="140">
    <div style="position:relative; width:140; height:600; z-index:1;">
        <img height="100%" width="100%" src="core_rec/web_res/menubg.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; z-index:0;">
        <iframe src="iframes/menus/main.html" width="140" id="sidebar" height="600">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</td>
```

that is supposed to have a background div containing an image, and on top of it in the same space, an iframe with a transparent background, so that I can change the iframe content without reloading the image. But when I try to display that code, the two divs are separate, the image on top, and then the iframe below it. I can't understand why they aren't stacking like they should.

I hesitate to make an absolute reference, so if possible I'd try to make the positions of both dynamic to the cell. Is the only way to make an absolute reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're going for, but [here's a fiddle using a negative `margin-top` to reposition everything](http://jsfiddle.net/dcNd7/).

Comment: [link to the page.](http://acetech.net78.net/) The main body has what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yeah. Lemme put that code to the site. It didn't work locally, but sometimes local things don't work like http does.

Comment: If that answers your question, then you should "accept" the answer.

Comment: Yeah I remembered that I forgot as I left, and knew you'd probably remind me by the time I got back :D